# Problems estimating covariance matrices with small $n$, smaller $p$?

Tags: estimation, covariance, covariance-matrix, estimators, fat-tails

It is well known that estimating large covariance matrices from small samples is problematic. For instance, the $p \times p$ sample covariance matrix $\Sigma_n$, estimated from $n$ samples, is not necessarily a consistent estimator of the true covariance matrix $\Sigma$ when $p > n$.

In contrast, I am interested in the case where $p < n$, but with the caveat that $n$ is still relatively small; for instance, $n = 30$ and $p = 3$.

Is there a reference that details estimation errors that may arise using the sample covariance matrix in this case? In particular, if the data are heavy-tailed? Are there pathological cases? Google brings up plenty of results for the $p > n$ or $p \approx n$ cases, but not the one I'm interested in.

Comment: You are interested in some metric on the covariance matrix reflecting estimation errors, right? The components, variances and covariances, can generally be estimated consistently and without bias as long as the 4th moments exist.

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch: I am interested in estimating not just the individual components, but the full matrix including its structure (perhaps represented by eigenvalues and eigenvectors?). So, for instance, if it is possible for outliers to drastically change this structure even for $p < n$, I would want to know about that.

Comment: This is too vague. Of course, you will almost surely miss the real covariance matrix and it's structure. But how much can you tolerate?

Comment: @Horst If $n$ is specified to be small, consistency (a property in the limit) isn't really a consideration.